# Private repo over ssh, apt-get ignoring packages

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apt

I wanted to create a new private APT repository on my VPS. To secure it I have decided to connect via ssh and authenticate by private/public keys.

So on VPS I created a new account: **repo-usr**

```
useradd -m -d /home/repo-usr -s /bin/false repo-usr
```

After that as a root I generated keys via gpg as a root

```
sudo su
gpg --key-gen
```

So I retrieved a keyid, let's say **1234**

Then I cd into home of the **repo-usr** and create a repository there

```
cd /home/repo-usr
mkdir -p ubuntu/conf
```

And create two files inside conf.

**distributions**

```
Codename: xenial
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
SignWith: 1234
```

**options**

```
ask-passphrase
```

I add some package to repo via:

```
reprepro -b /home/repo-usr/ubuntu includedeb xenial main foo.deb
```

On my client computer I generate ssh key pair for **repo-usr** and put the public key in authorized keys on server side (in /home/repo-usr/.ssh/authorized_keys)
The generated private key I transfer to root on client.
I believe I have successfully authenticated however I am not sure.

In /etc/apt/sources.list I add:

```
deb ssh://repo-usr@sever.com:/home/repo-usr/ubuntu xenial main
```

And after cleaning apt cache and running apt-get update I see that apt just ignores the packages.

```
Ign:19 ssh://server.com/home/repo-usr/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 ssh://server.com/home/repo-usr/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

and so on...
On top of that I get

> Failed to fetch ssh://server.com/home/repo-usr/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Package
>   Read error - read(0: Success)

However Package file exists there and looks fine.

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong? Is the set up mentioned above correct for such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **repo-usr** must be provided with a shell.

```
usermod -s /bin/bash repo-usr
```

fixed the problem.